# Foreign trig problem from maths challenge book

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The question says (translated from Spanish):

> **9.** Find the “$x$” value for every case:

But I’m only interested in case **a.**

I initially tried to solve it as a proportion but that yielded a far too complicated answer. My next guess was to assume that the arrows signify "similarity" so I'm thinking that these triangles are mirror images and one is smaller than the other. I'm thinking that the answer can be found by thinking of this as a proportion but we have one side as an unknown and that we have to solve for the extra side.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: The arrows indicate that those lines are parallel. Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I have named the points in the figure. The arrows indicate that the line segments, $BA$ and $DC$, are parallel. Thus, the alternate angles are equal, i.e. $$\angle ABO=\angle OCD,\quad \angle BAO=\angle ODC.$$ Also, since vertically opposite angles are always equal, we have $\angle AOB=\angle DOC$. Thus, by AAA criterion, $\triangle AOB\sim\triangle DOC$.

This means that $$\frac{AB}{DC}=\frac{BO}{CO}$$$$\implies \frac{x+2}{15-x}=\frac{2x}{x-1}$$$$\implies (x+2)(x-1)=2x(15-x)$$ from which $x$ can be found.